# Counting threshold hits

Tags: ruby, loops, iterator, logic, time-series

Running solo and would like some help. If you had a series of numbers and wanted to keep count of how many times values cross barriers, how would you do this?

```
series = [1, 6, 2, 4, 1, 9, 2]
series.hit_counts(upper=7, middle=5, lower=3) #returns 3
```

**Details**

```
1 -> 6 = +1 (Going from 1 to 6 hits the lower and middle threshold)
6 -> 2 = +0 (The high value, 6, never reached the upper threshold although it crosses the middle)
2 -> 4 = +0 (2 is below the lower threshold but has not hit the middle)
4 -> 1 = +0 (The series still has not reached the middle threshold)
1 -> 9 = +1 (The series hit the middle threshold)
9 -> 2 = +1 (The series has hit the high and middle thresholds)
```

`hit_counts`: Counts how many times values reach either the upper or lower threshold then cross the middle threshold.

Upper limit: 7

Middle limit: 5

Lower limit: 3

The method in question would return `3`. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: It is not exactly clear when you count the change as a threshold hit. My initial guess would be that [a, b] is count as a hit only if `a` is outside of `upper..lower` range and when `a..b` includes `middle`. Correct? Also, there is an extra step in your details `9 -> 2` which does not occur in your initial array.

Comment: The comment seems to have been cut-off? Please let me know what's not clear

Comment: Hit enter too soon, edited now.

Comment: Thanks. Updated the question. The count is only incremented when previous values have reached the upper or lower thresholds. Therefore the method has to take more into account than just [previous_value, current_value]. When I tried to implement it myself, I ended up using a variable for holding the state (whether it reached the upper or lower threshold).

Comment: So in fact we only need to count pairs for which we crossed two thresholds?

Comment: Yes. The information indicating that thresholds have been crossed may exist outside of the current pair. Such as, (1 -> 4 then 4 -> 6), 4 to 6 doesn't indicate that the lower to middle thresholds have been crossed but in fact they have. Giving your solution a try now. Running into `cover?` method errors but I'll get pass that. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Aha, that the bit which was missing. In that case my solution won't work. Will update in a second.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59957/discussion-between-broisatse-and-dru).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken a different approach to solving your problem.

**Code**

```
INF = Float::INFINITY

def score(series, limits)
  last =
    case series.first
    when (-INF..limits[:LOWER]) then :LOWER
    when (limits[:UPPER]..INF)  then :UPPER
    else :MIDDLE
    end
  series[1..-1].count do |n|
    if limits[last] <= n
      score = (last == :LOWER && n >= limits[:MIDDLE])
      last =
        case n
        when (-INF..limits[:MIDDLE]-1) then :LOWER
        when (limits[:UPPER]..INF) then :UPPER
        else :MIDDLE
        end
    else
      score = (last == :UPPER && n <= limits[:MIDDLE])
      last =
        case n
        when (-INF..limits[:LOWER]) then :LOWER
        when (limits[:MIDDLE]+1..INF) then :UPPER
        else :MIDDLE
        end
    end
    score
  end
end
```

**Examples**

```
limits = { LOWER: 3, MIDDLE: 5, UPPER: 7 }

series = [1, 6, 2, 4, 1, 9, 2]
p score(series,limits)  #=> 3

series = [1,5,12,8,10,4,13,3,1,4,6,4,6,9,1]
p score(series, limits) #=> 5
```

@BroiSatse gets the same results for these two test sequences.

**Explanation**

I've changed the rules to what I believe is a somewhat simpler problem that has the same scoring:

- Let `levels = {LOWER: 3, MIDDLE: 5, UPPER: 7}`
- A player starts at one of the three levels, `:LOWER`, `:MIDDLE` or `:UPPER`. If `f = series.first`, that level, held by the variable `last`, is:

  - `:LOWER`  if `f <= limits[:LOWER]`
  - `:UPPER`  if `f >= limits[:UPPER]`,
  - `:MIDDLE` otherwise
    `
- The player will move among levels (or remain at the current level), scoring `1` when moving from `:LOWER` to `:MIDDLE` or `:UPPER`, or when moving from `:UPPER` to `:MIDDLE` or `:LOWER`.
- For each `i > 0`, let `f = series[i]`. The player is located at `last`. The rules for moving and scoring are as follows:

  - if `limits[last] <= f` (moving to a non-decreasing value) the player moves to (and `last` becomes):

    - `:LOWER`  if `f <  limits[:MIDDLE]`
    - `:UPPER`  if `f >= limits[:UPPER]`
    - `:MIDDLE` otherwise
    - A point is scored if the player moves from `:LOWER` to either `:MIDDLE` or `:UPPER`.
      `
  - if `f < limits[last]` (moving to a decreasing value) the player moves to (and `last` becomes):

    - `:LOWER`  if `f <= limits[:LOWER]`
    - `:UPPER`  if `f >  limits[:MIDDLE]`
    - `:MIDDLE` otherwise
    - A point is scored if the player moves from `:UPPER` to either `:MIDDLE` or `:LOWER`.
- The process is repeated for each subsequent element in the sequence.

The code merely implements these rules in a straightforward way.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand what you want here, you can try sth like:

```
class Array
  def hit_counts(upper=7, middle=5, lower=3)
    limit_broken = false
    each_cons(2).count do |a,b|
      limit_broken = true unless (lower..upper).cover? a
      current_range = Range.new(*[a,b].sort)
      if limit_broken && current_range.cover?(middle)
        limit_broken = false
        true
      else
        false
      end
    end
  end
end
```